# Best way to use Prototype [OOP]

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, optimization, prototype

Can you please recommend which of the following is the best or their pros and cons?
I am not sure, but maybe, it depends on the type of use ?
Is one heavier than the other in terms of performance (keeping the class in memory etc.) ?

Thanks in advance!

**Method 1**

```
var MyClass = function(something) {
    this.something = something;
}
MyClass.prototype = {
    myMethod: function(arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
        return this.arg;
    },
    mySecondMethod: function() {
            return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
var MyClass = (function () {

    function MyClass(something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
        return this.arg;
    };
    MyClass.prototype.mySecondMethod = function (arg) {
            return "helloWorld";
    }

    return MyClass;
})();
```

Comment: There's no difference in how you are using the prototype. The revealing module pattern ("method 2") is unnecessary in your case, but probably won't to anything bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main differences:

1. In the first method, you are replacing the default prototype with an entirely new object. That's okay, but instances of MyClass will then inherit the wrong `constructor` property. You can fix that with:

   ```
   MyClass.prototype = {
       constructor: MyClass
       myMethod: // etc...
   ```

   Or simply extend the default prototype:

   ```
   var MyClass = function(something) {
       this.something = something;
   }
   MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function(arg) {
       this.arg = arg;
       return this.arg;
   }
   ```
2. In the second method, you wrapped the whole thing in an immediately-invoked function. This is useful if you want to have "private" (actually, private-like) variables, as variables declared inside will be visible by functions declared inside, but won't leak to the outer scope:

   ```
   var MyClass = (function () {
       var privateVar = "something"; // this will be visible by the functions
                                     // below but not outside

       function MyClass(something) {
           this.something = something;
       }

       MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (arg) {
           this.arg = arg;
           return this.arg;
       };

       // You were missing this
       return MyClass;
    })();
   ```

These are the differences. Both ultimately do the same thing: create a constructor, with some properties/methods attached to the prototype. There's no difference in terms of "optimization".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is one better than the other to create "optimized" Classes or are they "just different" in syntax form ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my code (added two methods) in order to be more precise.

Comment: @Antho Okay, I updated my answer based on your update and comments